# Maximum Number of Email Forwarders cPanel

Tags: apache, cpanel

Are there any limiting factors to consider when creating a large number(<10,000) of email forwarders through cPanel?

Is there a max file size to /etc/valiases or something I'm not seeing off the bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of forwarders, you can add unlimited forwarders through cPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer!